# Spring Batch Restart having Eureka Client in dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am having a problem when i try to restart a failed batch job with discovery client enabled. Every thing worked fine if i don't have `@EnableDiscoveryClient` but when i do enable it i got

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct type
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot construct type
cause-exception     : java.lang.InstantiationException
cause-message       : java.util.Map$Entry
construction-type   : java.util.Map$Entry
class               : java.util.Map$Entry
required-type       : java.util.Map$Entry
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /map/map/entry
line number         : -1
class[1]            : java.util.HashMap
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
version             : 1.4.9
-------------------------------
```

i traced the error and found that it is in `JdbcExecutionContextDao` when trying to deserialize(in)

```
private class ExecutionContextRowMapper implements RowMapper<ExecutionContext> {

        @Override
        public ExecutionContext mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            String serializedContext = rs.getString("SERIALIZED_CONTEXT");
            if (serializedContext == null) {
                serializedContext = rs.getString("SHORT_CONTEXT");
            }

            Map<String, Object> map;
            try {
                ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedContext.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                map = serializer.deserialize(in);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to deserialize the execution context", ioe);
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                executionContext.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            return executionContext;
        }
    }
```

checking the version and type of `serializer` did not lead me to any thing as both are the same and i am trying to deserialze same string

```
{"map":[{"entry":[{"string":"activeSheetId","int":-1},{"string":"acceptPendingDelete","int":-1},{"string":"expiryDateValue","long":7},{"string":"decreaseGracePeriod","long":0},{"string":"countryList","set":[""]},{"string":"acceptRemovedPrefix","int":-1},{"string":"increaseGracePeriod","long":7},{"string":"highPeriod","long":14},{"string":["carrierName","XXXX"]},{"string":"acceptRemovedCountry","int":-1},{"string":"acceptFutureIgnore","int":-1},{"string":"carrierId","long":1168},{"string":"highIncreaseValue","long":2}]}]}
```

Comment: do you have any serializers customization for Context storage?

Comment: no i don't have any. Same serialized string above will work when `@EnableDiscoveryClient` is disabled

Comment: Do you also have this exception only on startup? Do you run batch job immediately on start of application?

Comment: Currently on the testing i am doing the job is run automatically at start , but the problem started when i tried to request a job restart through rest , so i think it is not related ,i will double check though

Comment: Do you have a sample that illustrates this?

Comment: I am trying to come up with simple sample that I can publish and reproduce the error but until now i am not able to reproduce the above error except of the full project . Not sure what other dependency is effecting this i will try to eliminate stuff one by one to see.

Comment: @MichaelMinella i did create a sample at [https://github.com/shahbour/batch-task-serializer]

Comment: @shahbour, I think you have that in a private repo.  I get a 404 when I go to it.

Comment: @MichaelMinella this is the correct link [sample](https://github.com/shahbour/batch-task-serializer)

Answer (score 1):

Ok after lot of investigation i found how to reproduce the problem and how to fix it

a sample project at https://github.com/shahbour/batch-task-serializer will show how to reproduce the error and how to fix it.

Basically what i did is move the batch dependency in pom to the top of the dependency section and problem is solved.

i found that if i include spring-batch at the bottom (we will face the error) i will end up with two stax-api
`stax-api-1.0.1.jar` `stax-api-1.0-2.jar`

```
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
...
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator-core:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-grapher:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
```

while if i put it at top (project will work) i will end with one stax-api `stax-api-1.0-2.jar`

```
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator-core:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-grapher:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
```

Comment: @MichaelMinella should i create a bug on this , and if yes what project

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue and resolved by adding following dependency in POM.

1. Adding Jettison 1.2/1.3 Dependency.

Answer (score -1):

So after our discussion in comments I think Eureka has not much to do with this problem. It might affect behaviour because of bean initialization sequence.

What I think problem is - when you try to invoke job through rest request you most likely are using `JobOperator` and `JobExplorer`.

Try to initialize `JobExplorer` like this:

```
@Bean
public JobExplorer jobExplorer(DataSource dataSource, ExecutionContextSerializer serializer) throws Exception {
    JobExplorerFactoryBean fac = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
    fac.setDataSource(dataSource);
    fac.setSerializer(serializer);
    fac.afterPropertiesSet();
    return fac.getObject();
}
```

Where important part is that you take exactly same `serializer` which is used by spring batch.

Comment: that did not work , i am trying to create a sample project to reproduce the issue

Comment: it is really weird, in the sample project i was planning to share  i almost created all my project with all dependency and it is working fine . now i am comparing both to see what is the difference

Comment: Yeah, usually it helps. I had a similar problem, and when I made an sample project I've found out that my suspects were innocent ;) Please write here if you will find something out.

Comment: It occurred due to Eureka